# Long delays and slow performance of Server 2K8 R2 VM after upgrade

Tags: windows-server-2008, server-message-block

I used to have a Server 2003 R2 Hyper-V VM instance running on an Server 2012 R2. The performance was very good. THen, I was told that 2003 wasn't being supported anymore by a software package I use, so I upgraded to 2008 R2, and that's when all my SMB shares took a nosedive.

When I attempt to navigate to my network drive using SMB2 (verified using wireshark), When I open a folder, it takes almost a minute to list the content of the folder. Using 2003, it was instantaneous. Then, when I move my mouse cursor over a file in the folder, windows explorer locks up for another minute. Wireshark doesn't produce anything other than Keep-Alive messages while I wait for a response from the server. Any ideas as to why this is happening after my upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

A guess is that you're having issues with Windows' file/search indexing. There's quite a lot of material on that if you do a web search.

That said: Why migrate from one unsupported OS to another? Windows 2008 R2 has been deprecated too since a while back. (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4456235/end-of-support-for-windows-server-2008-and-windows-server-2008-r2)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It's because that OS is supported (for now). You think upgrading again will resolve my problem or exacerbate it?

Comment: The OS may be supported by the software vendor, but not by Microsoft, which is a bad thing. In your shoes I would ensure I have backups, try to solve the issue, then upgrade to the newest OS version supported by the software vendor. That is unless a clean install is an option, in which case I would strongly prefer that. The latter option would likely lead to less downtime and allow more experimenting before going live.

Comment: I totally agree, stick with the supported versions only, to minimize the number of issues you are facing. You can always check Microsoft support matrix here: 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search/1163

Answer (score 0):

I took the suggestion and reinstalled on the newest Server version, and things are back to normal. Because I didn't have much software installed other than making this a NFS sharing server, the time to get back to normal wasn't too bad. Thanks, and sorry for not being able to help anyone else who might have the same problem I had after upgrade.